# ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Tags: python

Can someone please help me resolve the error code I get in the title.

I've tried adding float as mentioned in stuff I've read online, but this doesn't work either.

```
`df['Conv. Rates']=df['Conv. Rates'].apply(lambda x: " 
{0:.2f}%".format(x))
df.head()`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/_c/86br91rx4fx2j35rrmbfkp6h0000gn/T/ipykernel_6452/1132564018.py in <module>
----> 1 df['Conv. Rates']=df['Conv. Rates'].apply(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x))
      2 df.head()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4431         dtype: float64
   4432         """
-> 4433         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4434 
   4435     def _reduce(

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
   1086             return self.apply_str()
   1087 
-> 1088         return self.apply_standard()
   1089 
   1090     def agg(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1141                 # List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]]]]]"; expected
   1142                 # "Callable[[Any], Any]"
-> 1143                 mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1144                     values,
   1145                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/var/folders/_c/86br91rx4fx2j35rrmbfkp6h0000gn/T/ipykernel_6452/1132564018.py in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['Conv. Rates']=df['Conv. Rates'].apply(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x))
      2 df.head()

ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: you not included image reference??

Comment: Hello @john palma, Please try including more information in your question such as your code and other things that could help us answer your question. You could do so with editing your question. Also try reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it can help you a lot

Comment: I've updated my post with the code, please help me understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `x` is a string and not a float as you expect, so `"12.345"` is just six characters, the same as if it were `"python"`, and Python doesn't know how to format it with decimal points.

You can do

```
df['Conv. Rates'].astype("float")
```